# Dynamically resize custom xib cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xib

so I'm having some trouble with my custom xib cell not dymanicall resizing based on the UILabel's inside of the cell. I have set

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 250
    }
```

**XIB Cell ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ReminderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var notesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    backgroundColor = .clear // very important
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowRadius = 4

    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2 , height: 2)
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor

    // add corner radius on `contentView`
    contentView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    progressBar.transform = progressBar.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 5)
    progressBar.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    progressBar.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 15
    self.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


func setInfo(title:String, notes:String,date:String){
    titleLabel.text = title
    notesLabel.text = notes
    dateLabel.text = date
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 10))
}

 }
```

**Constraints on the XIB**
[image: xib constraints]

**What it looks like**
[image: Look]

I have the lines for both the titleLabel and the userNotes set to 0 and also have word wrap on both.

If you guys can help me out I'd love that thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

once you should try like this.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 250
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```